# On global section of a line bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, principal-bundles, line-bundles

At Proposition 1.1.1. (1) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0494.pdf it is written that $H^0(X, L \otimes {\cal{J}}(X, ||L||)) = H^0(X, L)$ ensures that every global holomorphic section $s$ of $L$, i.e., $s \in H^0(X, L)$, vanishes at ${\cal{J}}(X, ||L||)$. I cannot make head or tail of what it means actually.

Suppose that $L = {\cal O}_X(D)$ and $M = {\cal O}_X(E)$ for chosen Cartier divisros $D, E$. The zero loci $D(s) \colon= \{x \in X \,|\, s(x) =0\}$ of the global holomorphic section $s \in H^0(X, L)$ is linearly equivalent to $D$. Then what follows from the condition that $H^0(X, {\cal O}_X(D)) = H^0(X, {\cal O}_X(D) \otimes_{\cal{O}_X} {\cal O}_X(E))$?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{J}(X,||L||)$?

Comment: ${\cal{J}}(X, ||L||) = {\cal{J}}(X, \frac{1}{p}D_p)$, where $D_p \in H^0(X, L^{\otimes p})$. That is the defining ideal of $\frac{1}{p}D_p$.

Comment: I still don't understand --- what is the defining ideal of a divisor with rational coefficients? E.g., what is the ideal of $\frac12 C$ if $C$ is a plane conic?